# Translating a proposition into propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to translate a proposition into propositional logic.

> There do not exist an infinite number of naturals or I become a programmer if I take the train.

It is a bit strange to me, because I do not really know how to translate `there do... or ..`

I suppose it is an exclusive or proposition.

```
p -> there exist an infinite number of naturals
q -> I become a programmer
r -> I take the train

And this is how I understand it:

r if (not p xor q)
```

Can somebody help me with an explanation to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to understand... Format the formulas and proceed step-by-step: "not-p or (q if r)"

Comment: sorry, I think I formulated it ambiguous. I mean that I would like to translate that sentence from English to propositional logic, and I do not know whether I understand it correctly.

Comment: Your proposed solution parse the natural language statement in a different way; maybe correct... First step, decide what is the correct reading.

Comment: I do not know whether I read correct the statement. English is not my first language and I am a bit worried that I misunderstand the semantic of it.

Comment: Agreed; IMO there are two possible readings: either (i) "not-p or (q if r)" above, that is: $(r \to q) \lor \lnot p$; or (ii) "(not-p or q) if r", that is:  $r \to (\lnot p \lor q)$. Up to you...

Comment: You have to decide between these two equally-possible interpretations before proceeding to translate it to symbolic logic: (1) Either there does not exist an infinite number of naturals, or if I take the train then I become a programmer, or both. (2) If I take the train, then either there does not exist an infinite number of naturals, or I become a programmer, or both.

Comment: @ryang so, in the second translation, I have to apply an implication of an exclusive or?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much sir! I thought that there is only one way to do so. Hopefully, I ll pick up the right one! Thank you!

Comment: No, in formal logic, "$A$ or $B$" translates as "either $A$ or $B$ or both". I added "or both" to make explicit our presumption that the given sentence is also using the inclusive 'or'.

Comment: @ryang Great! Thank you very much! I much appreciate your help!